# How to write file creation script?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am very new to scripting and would like to know how to write a script `fileCreate` which has two optional parameters two input arguments as shown below:

```
fileCreate <filename> <path>
```

`<filename>` parameter signifies the name of the file in which the 
           contents will be saved

`<path>` parameter signifies the directory structure where the file will 
       be saved.

When the program is executed it will open an editor and user can input any contents, that will be saved as specified.

If no parameters are passed, the default is current directory and `userfileX` (`userfileX` to the number of times the file is created)

If there already exists a file of similar name and having same contents then the user should be able to append the file or else just the date gets modified.

Comment: fileCreate will take command as: fileCreate <filename> <pathname>

Comment: This site is not here to ask other people to do some job... Show your implemenation and then you'll be able to ask here for any doubt about *the code* you wrote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vi as the editor:

```
D=${2:-.}

F=$1
if [ -z "$F" ] ; then
    X=1
    F="userfile$X"
    while [ -f "$F" ] ; do
        X=$(($X+1))
        F="userfile$X"
    done
fi

vi "$D/$F"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I would like ask you one more thing. I am using the alias filecreate = 'touch $3' too in the script but while running the required file is not getting created in the current directory.

Comment: @DipankarDeka you're welcome, remember to upvote answers that help and accept answers that are right to the question :) `$3` means you should call the script with a third argument. It would be good if you would edit your question to give the script you're using.

Comment: okay...but how do i solve this problem, suppose a userfile has been created by running the script and then in the terminal we create a file using cat > userfile12. Now when I run the script again then the new file to be created should be userfile13 since userfile12 was the last file that already exists.

Comment: @DipankarDeka did you already write a script? If so you should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36859162/edit) to include it. Without that I don't know where the `cat > userfile12` is coming from...