# Custom command creation

Tags: linux, shell

I have used the command `alias filecreate='touch $1'` in my script to create a new file in my present working directory with the help of filecreate as custom command. But when I execute the script it's showing error. Also how do I make the command to accept 2 parameters one the filename and other the pathname.

Comment: What script? What error?

Comment: `alias` cannot accept parameters. If you need to handle parameters, use a function.

Comment: Same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36859162/1098603

Answer (score 3):

`alias filecreate=touch`

or its function equivalent:

```
filecreate(){ touch "$@"; }
```

will accept an arbitrary number of arguments and pass them to `touch`.

Positional argument expansions usually don't belong in aliases, as aliases, unlike functions, don't get their own positional argument arrays.
Aliases are simple text expansions.

Your

```
alias filecreate='touch "$1"'
```

when run like so:

```
filecreate SomeFile
```

would simply expand to

```
 filecreate "$1" SomeFile #$1 comes from the caller
```

This differs from functions and scripts, which do get their own argument array.

Comment: [Original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36859162/1098603) ;) Also, I think you meant it expands to `touch "$1" SomeFile`

Comment: Thank you everybody appreciate your help. @PSkocik I created the function with filecreate.